# Is continuous integration useful for a team of two developers who write a lot of code?

Tags: continuous-integration

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How many developers before continuous integration becomes effective for us?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/64592/how-many-developers-before-continuous-integration-becomes-effective-for-us)

I'm new with continous integration though I have used it without know the term. So, I'm interested about the mechanism can be possible to implement and my question is: can a continuous integration server be useful for a team of two developers? (but that write a lot of code)

Answer (score 3):

Its probably better for a team that writes a lot of code. It allows you to worry about writing code, leaving the CI server to automatically run release builds, check dependancies and some static analysis - if you're doing your job right, it'll be silently compiling your checkins. If you're getting things wrong, it'll email you what errors it's finding.

If you get a lot of emails from it, then its obvious you're not working together very well, the emails will tell you what areas you need to look into, whether that's because you're writing poor code, or checking in code that breaks the other's code.